# Image of a smooth hypersurface under the Veronese embedding

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $n, d > 0$ be integers. Let $N = {n+d \choose d}-1$ and let $v_d : \mathbb{P}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^N$ be the $d$-uple Veronese embedding.

If $H$ is a smooth hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^n$, is the image $v_d (H)$ smooth?

Also, is the preimage of a smooth hypersurface under $v_d$ smooth?

Comment: A very standard exercise about the $d$-uple embedding is that it's an isomorphism on to its image. Your first question is exactly resolved by that, and if you don't know this, you should consider proving it on your own. For your second question, do you mean a smooth hypersurface inside $v_d(\Bbb P^n)$, or a smooth hypersurface in $\Bbb P^N$?

Comment: @KReiser I meant inside $v_d (\mathbb{P}^n)$.